# What does pointer doubling mean in the context of arrays in Java?

Tags: java

> Find a duplicate. Given an array of N+1 elements in which each element is an integer between 1 and N, write an algorithm to find a duplicate. Your algorithm should run in linear time, use O(1) extra space, and may not modify the original array. Hint: pointer doubling.

I'm trying to solve this problem from a book. What does pointer doubling mean in this context? 
The book uses Java so I'm assuming this must be something applicable to Java as well even though there is no concept of pointers in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think I could add anything beyond the content on this web page:

http://aperiodic.net/phil/archives/Geekery/find-duplicate-elements.html

Your actual problem of O(n) runtime and O(1) space is addressed approximately halfway down the page, and what I assume must be "pointer doubling" is suggested as the best solution. The basic pseudocode for solving the problem is given as:

```
let i ← n, j ← n
do: i ← A[i], j ← A[A[j]]; until i = j
set j ← n
do: i ← A[i], j ← A[j]; until i = j
return i
```

Though I would recommend visiting the site as the explanation is much more thorough than any I could give.

Comment: -1 for solving the problem, rather than answering the question.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what pointer doubling officially means, but by using each element in the array as both a counter and a value, you can solve this. I am intentionally not providing the full solution because I suspect you want to figure it out on your own.

One hint: all numbers in the array are ints, but positive. You know that N < MAX_INT. Can you use that to your advantage?